# Calculating elapsed time based on a condition

Tags: r

I want to make a calculation what the average elapsed time between stages is when a condition is fulfilled but i'm completely puzzeled about how to do it. I generated a dummy dataset. In the result column you have two condition ('Failure','Sucess'). What I want to calculate is when the first 'Failure' appears, how long does it take until there is a 'Success' again. For example:

> Success -> Success -> Failure -> Failure -> Failure -> Success -> Failure -> Success

Since the time between every step is 24h we count from the first 'Failure' until the first 'Success' appears again. Thats 3x24h=72hours in this case. Then again it is Success and then Failure and then Success again 1x24h. Thats (4*24h)/2=48h average time. Thanks :)

```
library(lubridate)
id        <- c(1:10)
result    <- c('Success', 'Success', 'Failure', 'Failure', 'Success', 'Failure', 'Failure', 'Failure', 'Success', 'Failure' )
time      <- c("2018-07-12 12:24:00 CEST", "2018-07-11 19:31:00 CEST", "2018-07-10 08:12:00 CEST", "2018-07-09 02:22:00 CEST", "2018-07-08 22:33:00 CEST", "2018-07-07 12:34:00 CEST", "2018-07-06 07:55:00 CEST", "2018-07-05 03:44:00 CEST", "2018-07-04 17:33:00 CEST", "2018-07-03 19:22:00 CEST")
df        <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, result, time))
df$result <- as.factor(df$result)  
df$time   <- ymd_hms(df$time)
df
```

Comment: Your logic is weird. if you skip the first failure, and count 2*24 if you have sfffs, how do you count 2 failures in a row (sffs)? 24, as you do when you have just 1 failure?  from a logic standpoint I would just count the failures and treat each failure as 24hrs.

Comment: @phiver: You are correct, I miscounted :( I did the edits.

Comment: Looks like your time column is reversed. earliest time is for id 10. Is this the way you get the data?

Comment: Yes it is reversed, because the database writes it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example df:
time difference is calculated from the first failure(s) to the first new success time. So counting forwards. This is way the last time is still NA, since there is no record afterwards. res_count takes this into consideration that as long as this record is NA, it doesn't count with creating the average.

```
library(dplyr)


   df %>% 
  mutate(res_time = ifelse(result == "Failure", time - lead(time), 0),
         res_count = ifelse(result == "Failure" & result != lag(result) & !is.na(res_time), 1, 0)) %>% 
  summarise(average_time = sum(res_time, na.rm = TRUE) / sum(res_count))

  average_time
1     50.33333
```

if you stop before the summarise you have a table like this:

```
   id  result                time  res_time res_count
1   1 Success 2018-07-12 12:24:00  0.000000         0
2   2 Success 2018-07-11 19:31:00  0.000000         0
3   3 Failure 2018-07-10 08:12:00 29.833333         1
4   4 Failure 2018-07-09 02:22:00  3.816667         0
5   5 Success 2018-07-08 22:33:00  0.000000         0
6   6 Failure 2018-07-07 12:34:00 28.650000         1
7   7 Failure 2018-07-06 07:55:00 28.183333         0
8   8 Failure 2018-07-05 03:44:00 10.183333         0
9   9 Success 2018-07-04 17:33:00  0.000000         0
10 10 Failure 2018-07-03 19:22:00        NA         1
```

Comment: Hi, the time is not 24h between them, its random. I just did it in the example to make it easier to understand, sorry. I already modified the data to make it more realistic.